# Cache friendliness of randomly accessing a contiguous array

Tags: c++, cpu-cache

So I'm writing a custom scripting language specifically for ECS like applications, and as the whole point of ECS is to minimize cache misses I figured I might as well apply that to the scripting language as well. Currently my interpreter uses a virtual stack (`std::vector<std::byte>`) to store all of it's variables. I was wondering if the fact that the memory that my interpreter uses contiguous memory makes it more cpu cache friendly. Since the memory is being semi randomly accessed (Though mostly close together) I'm guessing the benefits wouldn't be as good as if I were reading them in a sequential and predictable fashion. What are your thoughts wise people of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Just like the call stack in native asm, the end of your stack that's currently in use will tend to stay hot in cache, so random access that's mostly within a few 64-byte cache lines is totally fine.  And yes, much better than using `new` to get possibly-scattered space for each variable.

Comment: "*I figured I might as well apply that to the scripting language as well.*" Um... why? Scripting languages are *going to be slower* than not using a scripting language. By using it, you're willingly sacrificing performance for some benefit (ease of modification, user-friendliness, rapid prototyping, in-situ code modification, etc). While the performance of your scripting language shouldn't be ignored, you shouldn't undertake Herculean efforts for it either. Not without serious profiling saying that your application's performance needs it.

Comment: "*the whole point of ECS is to minimize cache misses*" No, it's not. ECS was invented to avoid fat interfaces and the other foibles of using OOP to design an entity class. That one *can* use ECS to improve data locality is a useful benefit, but it's not the "whole point" of the thing at all.

Comment: Define "cache"? There are several involved here. Define "friendly"? This is subjective.

Comment: @tadman: It's tagged [cpu-cache], so I think it's safe to assume we're talking about the CPU accessing main memory through its cache hierarchy.  And given the mention of data variables, I also assume it's asking about data accesses, not caching of compiled machine-code (L1i cache / uop cache).

Comment: @PeterCordes The trouble with talking about "cache" is it's not a unified thing. L1, L2, L3,  data versus code, and how it varies *considerably* depending on the hardware involved. There's really no way to answer this short of doing some very careful, in-depth benchmarks, but I'm not sure that'd be especially educational short of having a measurable performance problem to start with.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm just asking because this question sounds reasonable superficially, but gets really difficult to pin down to specifics. How much data? How random? This really needs code for context.

Comment: @tadman: A very general answer is possible, though, like the first comment under the question.  Contiguous data is always good for caches, if multiple accesses are close enough that more than 1 are in the same cache line.  And even if not, it reduces the danger of conflict misses because only distant addresses will map to the same set in any given level of cache.  So yeah, I don't think it's answerable beyond my initial comment without a lot more details, and thus doesn't seem very useful (which is why I didn't upvote or answer, so to some degree I agree with you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contiguous memory is nice, because many parts of the memory subsystem benefit from locality of reference. But the scale at which the various parts work varies. Typically CPU cache lines are smaller than the page size, e.g. 64 bytes vs 4096 bytes. Your vector will likely span multiple cache lines, so contiguity at that scale does not really matter, but it would benefit from contiguity at the page size.